# How would I convert this query with multiple ors to eloquent format?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I need to run this query, which works properly in MYSQL

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE title_id = 4 AND (state_a = 'TRUE' OR state_b = 'TRUE' OR state_c = 'TRUE')
```

I have tried the following, and a few other options, but get results seemingly at random.

```
    $values = \App\Time_Code::select('id','title_id','type','state_a','state_b','state_c')
                        ->where('title_id', '=', '4')
                        ->where('state_a', '=', 'TRUE')
                        ->orWhere('state_b', '=', 'TRUE')
                        ->orWhere('state_c', '=', 'TRUE')
                        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                        ->get();
```

Am I completely going in the wrong direction here? In this case it is including rows with title_ids that are not 4. Also it returns the entire row, not just the requested fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write a nested query to reflect your condition nesting in MySQL:

```
$values = \App\Time_Code::select('id','title_id','type','state_a','state_b','state_c')
                    ->where('title_id', '=', '4')
                    ->where(function ($q) {
                         $q->where('state_a', '=', 'TRUE')
                           ->orWhere('state_b', '=', 'TRUE')
                           ->orWhere('state_c', '=', 'TRUE');
                           })
                    ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
```

See the manual on [Parameter Grouping](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#parameter-grouping).